# How to find out whether application running on IIS using JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Is there any way I can find out my ASP.Net application running on IIS or locally on Visual studio using JavaScript?

Comment: Why do you need to know that by javascript?

Comment: the question is not clear

Comment: I need to find exact application path for both the situations in java script. for example, locally http://localhost:8943 or on IIS http://localhost/mysite

Comment: I think you want to check if javascript is enabled client side

Comment: `window.location` maybe all you really need... But sending the data from server itself (i.e. as suggested by Alexander) is likely safe/easier approach.

Comment: good question I don't know why is the downvote I need it too to know the path to my controller!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Request.Url.AbsoluteUri to get site url. Write it in hidden field and then use in javascript.

Comment: +1. I think it is most reliable approach (may need to tweak what exactly to send, I.e. `MapServerPatt("~\") `... The only problem could be if site is behind some sort of proxy/CDN/url rewrite which will hide original Url, but it is unlikely the case for 99% of sites.